# How to set <img> alt tag from another piece of HTML in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website which was set up at a time when I knew even less about this business than I do now. The site contains about two hundred pages and several thousand images.  The HTML to display them usually looks like this:

```
<div class="pic">
<a onclick="loadImage('filename.jpg')" href="#4"><img   src="filename.jpg" alt="missing img"></a>
<div class="imgcapt"><i>Caption</i></div>
</div>
```

This puts an image on the page with a caption underneath.  Clicking on the image opens a larger version of the image in a new window.  Most of the images have captions but not all of them.

What I want to do is to replace the existing alt text with the contents of the imgcapt div (where one exists). Ideally, I would like to do this in the source files but, if that's not possible, then to add some JavaScript which would do it at page load time. I've looked at various answers to similar questions but cannot find anything that matches. Can anybody point me in the right direction for either of these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jQuery to select all div's with pic class

Then for each match get the text of the i inside the imgcapt class and set the attribute alt to the a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.pic').each(function(el) {
    var imgCaption = $(this).find('i').text();
    $(this).find('img').prop('alt', imgCaption);
  })
});
```

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3vmd92zr/

Answer (score 0):

no neeed for jquery,
you can check the document.querySelector('div.imgcapt')`.innerHTML` of you .imgcapt element´
and set the alt tag with element.setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use inline HTML event handlers (`onclick=...`) as they create spaghetti code, cause global anonymous function proxies that modify the `this` binding and don't follow DOM Event standards.

Second, you don't need to wrap your images in anchor tags at all. Just wire up the click event of the image to your function.

So, this would do it:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  
  for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; ++i){
     imgs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        window.location = this.getAttribute("data-path");
        loadImage("fileName.jpg");
        this.alt = this.nextElementSibling.firstChild.innerHTML;
        alert(this.alt);
     });
  }

  function loadImage(path){
    window.open(path);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<div class="pic">
  <img src="filename.jpg" alt="missing img" data-path="#4">
  <div class="imgcapt"><i>Caption</i></div>
</div>
```